# SuperAgent EndAsync

Tags: javascript, promise, superagent

**Superagent** Documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent-as-promised says:

```js
request
  .get('/location')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log("Got " + response.text);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.dir(error);
  })
```

Is syntactic sugar for:

```js
var promise = request
  .get('/location')
  .endAsync();

promise
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log("Got " + response.text);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.dir(error);
  });
```

But `endAsync()` method sounds like waiting on a `Promise` to resolve, is that true? If that is true then line:

```js
request
  .get('/location')
  .endAsync();
```

Looks like a sync call.

Is that true?

Comment: yes it does wait

Comment: `looks like a sync call` - yeah, but nothing can turn asynchronous into synchronous, so, yeah, it **looks** like it, but probably isn't

Comment: So should the above code be written as var promise = request
  .get('/location') ? i.e. without endAsync(), what does endAsync() adding there?